# Calling base class property from object of derived class without marking it virtual

Tags: c#, oop

How to call x of class a from object of class b without marking x of class a as virtual.
Is it possible

```
public class a { public int x { get; set; } }
public class b : a { public int x { get; set; } }

public class c {
    a _a = new a();
    b _b = new b();
    public c()
    {
        int y=_a.x;
        y=_b.x;
        _b.x = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`base.x()` should work inside the `b` type (but that isn't what you have here).

In the "method hiding" scenario (what you have), it also largely depends on what a variable is **typed** as, so casting to `a` should work:

```
a tmp = _b;
tmp.x = ... // talks to a.x, not b.x
```

or more succinctly:

```
((a)_b).x = ... // talks to a.x, not b.x
```

Answer (score 2):

Use typecast:

```
public class c
{
  a _a = new a();
  b _b = new b();

  void Test() {
    int y = _b.x; // This is "x" of "b"
    a _b_as_a = (a)_b;
    int z = _b_as_a.x; // This is "x" of "a" of "b"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't it work using base. If i have to call using base keyword how do i need to structure my class. I know to using virtual i can get what i want, this question is just for clearing some doubts

Comment: @Shantanu `base` means only "the base of `c`", aka `object`. You can't use `base` when talking to any object except `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides typecasting (as above, although that won't work if you don't know its parent's type) you can't, so I would advise re-structuring one of those classes. You should probably make x virtual, or change the property x inside class b to something different, or call base.x inside b's x implementation.

Comment: if you *specifically want* `a.x`, you know the type... plus for classes the type is rigid anyway....